# Redux Form: Input stays with 'touched: false'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, redux, redux-form

Wanted to validate my inputs and change the CSS depending of the user interaction.

Starting with a required validation method I wrap all my inputs component with a `<Field>` and pass to `validate` an array of func. Just `required` for now.

But for all my fields the value stay the same `touched: false` and `error: "Required"`. If I touch or add stuff in the input, those values stay the same.

**Validation**

```
export const required = value => (value ? undefined : 'Required')
```

**NameInput**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Field } from 'redux-form'
import InputItem from 'Components/InputsUtils/InputItem';
import { required } from 'Components/InputsUtils/Validation';

const NameInput = () => (
  <Field
    name={item.spec.inputName}
    type={item.spec.type}
    component={InputItem}
    validate={[required]}
    props={item}
  />
);

export default NameInput;
```

**InputItem**

```
import React from 'react';

const InputItem = ({ spec, meta: { touched, error } }) => {        
  const { type, placeholder } = spec;
  return (
    <input
      className="input"
      type={type}
      placeholder={placeholder}
    />
  );
};

export default InputItem;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `redux-form` controls its own props within your `<input />` element as long as you use the spread operator to pass those props into your input.

For example, where you are doing `const InputItem = ({ spec, meta: { touched, error } }) => ...`

Try destructing the input from the Component: `const InputItem = ({ input, spec, meta: { touched, error } }) => ...`

And where you have your `<input ... />`, try doing the following:

```
<input
  {...input}
  className="input"
  type={type}
  placeholder={placeholder}
/>
```

The redux-form captures any `onBlur` and `onChange` events and uses its own methods to change the `touched` state. You just need to pass those along as shown above.

These are what you need: https://redux-form.com/7.1.2/docs/api/field.md/#input-props

Comment: Thank I miss this props. Now I have another issue. If I lose focus without the requirement (a simple value) I add a red check icone. But If I focus again then add something the icon doesn't change even if error's value goes to `undefined`.

See my EDIT.

Comment: That's odd, seems like your code should work fine. Does you see the '----Undefined-----' in your console?

Answer (score 11):

There are 2 solutions to solve the *"touched is always false"* issue.

**1) Ensure that [`input.onBlur`](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/field.md/#-code-input-onblur-eventorvalue-function-code-) is called in your component**

For an input:

```
const { input } = this.props

<input {...input} />
```

For custom form elements without native `onBlur`:

```
const { input: { value, onChange, onBlur } } = this.props

const className = 'checkbox' + (value ? ' checked' : '')

<div
  className={className}
  onClick={() => {
    onChange(!value)
    onBlur()
  }}
/>
```

**2) Declare your form with [`touchOnChange`](https://redux-form.com/8.1.0/docs/api/reduxform.md/#-code-touchonchange-boolean-code-optional-)**

```
const ReduxFormContainer = reduxForm({
  form: 'myForm',
  touchOnChange: true,
})(MyForm)
```

Answer (score 1):

Another point to consider:
I passed `{...props}` to my custom component, however, touched still remained false.
That is because although props contained the input object, my component couldn't
deduce onBlur from it. When explicitly stating `<CustomComponent {...this.props} onBlur={this.props.input.onBlur}`, it worked as expected.